# How can I terminate a worker in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and always run into a problem. I'd like to be able to add a new route that will terminate a specific worker profile. I provided below what I've added but when ever I type http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/terminate?profile=jackson it will start opening endless new browsers and showing this error: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!

Right now I have 10 workers running but sometimes I want to be able to close a few of them down without shutting off the entire server.

```
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");
const app = require("express")();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);

let portCounter = 9444;
let activeWorkers = {};

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.get("/api/chrome", (request, response) => {
  const profile = request.query.profile;

  const workerInstance = worker(profile, {
    remoteDebuggingPort: portCounter++,
  });

  activeWorkers[profile] = workerInstance;

  return response.status(200).send("Booting the browser");
});

app.get("/api/terminate", (request, response) => {
  const profile = request.query.profile;

  if (activeWorkers[profile]) {
    activeWorkers[profile].manualTermination = true; 
    activeWorkers[profile].worker.terminate();
    delete activeWorkers[profile];
    return response.status(200).send(`Worker ${profile} terminated`);
  } else {
    return response.status(404).send(`Worker ${profile} not found`);
  }
});

function worker(profile, data = {}) {
  const startWorker = () => {
    const worker = new Worker("./worker.js", {
      workerData: {
        ...data,
        profile: profile,
      },
    });

    worker.profile = profile;
    worker.manualTermination = false; 

    worker.on("message", (message) => {
      console.log(`Message back from worker: ${message}`);
    });

    worker.on("error", (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

    worker.on("exit", (code) => {
      console.log(`Worker exited - ${code} ++ ${worker.profile}`);
      if (!worker.manualTermination) {
        startWorker();
      }
    });

    return { worker, profile };
  };

  return startWorker();
}

http.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("HTTP server started on 127.0.0.1:8000");
});
```

This is what I tried.

```
app.get("/api/terminate", (request, response) => {
  const profile = request.query.profile;

  if (activeWorkers[profile]) {
    activeWorkers[profile].manualTermination = true;
    activeWorkers[profile].worker.terminate(); 
    delete activeWorkers[profile];
    return response.status(200).send(`Worker ${profile} terminated`);
  } else {
    return response.status(404).send(`Worker ${profile} not found`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can anyone help please